# Define options with class method in class like Action Mailer does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to have a module which can be included in class, and allow to set options for like this:

```
class MyService
  include Healthcheck

  healthcheck_id 'foobar'
end
```

And module will looks something like:

```
module Healthcheck
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.healthcheck_id(value)
      # What do I do here?
    end
  end
end
```

The question is: how do I store this value which was passed as argument, so that I can use it later on?

Maybe some context might help here, I was inspired by Action Mailer:

```
class ExampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "no-reply@example.com"
end
```

In the example above class method(?) `default` is accepting hash with arguments, and apparently `from` is used by Action Mailer when email is being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pb with [@hieu-pham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1789479/hieu-pham)'s solution is that you can't define different `healthcheck_id` values for different classes:

```ruby
class MyService1
  include Healthcheck

  healthcheck_id 'foobar_1'

  def foo
    puts healthcheck_id_value
  end
end

class MyService2
  include Healthcheck

  healthcheck_id 'foobar_2'

  def foo
    puts healthcheck_id_value
  end
end

MyService1.new.foo # foobar_2
MyService2.new.foo # foobar_2
```

A better solution would be:

```ruby
module Healthcheck
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :healthcheck_id_value

    def self.healthcheck_id(value)
      self.healthcheck_id_value = value
    end

    def self.foo
      healthcheck_id_value
    end
  end
end

class MyService1
  include Healthcheck

  healthcheck_id 'foobar_1'
end

class MyService2
  include Healthcheck

  healthcheck_id 'foobar_2'
end

MyService1.foo # foobar_1
MyService2.foo # foobar_2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use class variable to do it, so the code would be:

```
module Healthcheck
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def self.healthcheck_id(value)
      @@healthcheck_id_value = value
    end

    class_eval do
      def healthcheck_id_value
        self.class.class_variable_get(:@@healthcheck_id_value)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So from now on you can access `healthcheck_id_value`, for example:

```
class MyService
  include Healthcheck

  healthcheck_id 'foobar'

  def foo
    puts healthcheck_id_value
  end
end
```

Let's call `MyService.new.foo`, it will print 'foobar'

Comment: Not saying don't use class variables, just be careful with them around subclasses: `class MySubService < MyService; healthcheck_id 'barfoo'; end` and then `MyService.new.foo # => 'barfoo'; MySubService.new.foo # => 'barfoo'`

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a class variable

`@@arguments_passed = value`

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [ActionMailer::Base source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3a6e84715e042b3d445fc178e5c88f10e27620c2/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L519)

It uses ([`class_attribute :default_params`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3a6e84715e042b3d445fc178e5c88f10e27620c2/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L462))